# Can I specify a person to share with when implementing the Google+ share button?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'd like to implement the Google+ Share button in my site.
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/

It seems to default the share scope to 'Public'.  Is there a way to customize that and set it to a person or a circle?

In my use case the scope is known ahead of time.  I'd like to save the user the extra step of removing the public scope and typing in the person.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to programmatically set the recipients/circles of a message shared on Google+.